# Xamarin ios build error Error: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references

Tags: c#, ios, windows, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm unable to compile my Xamarin.iOS project. This project was recently migrated from .NET Standard 1.4 to a .NET Standard 2 project in VS2017 on Windows connect to the Mac Agent.

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing
>   references of 'Clients.iOS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'

This is part of the Build log:

```
 warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file.

Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" to Version "4.0.20.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.rning.

(1,1): error: Xamarin.FFImageLoading package not found for versions [2.2.20, ] on netstandard1.4
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you still see in your project a reference to the Xamarin.FFImageLoading nuget package? I was also wondering whether there is there a particular reason why you are not using the latest stable version (2.4.3.840) of this nuget package?

Comment: Try to delete the folder 'bin' and 'obj' ,then rebuild the project.

Comment: @MichaelC. I updated it but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have already deleted the folder 'bin' and 'obj'. But it didnt solve it.